# View Bulk Operation page Customization

Tags: views

i have created on view page which have option to update the node values but as a default behavior of VBO i first need to check the checkbox form my table and then click on update button then it goes to another page where i can select which value to be added 
[image]

After click on update button next page will come for selection of value

[image]

after this selection and next is clicked the value get updated...

here i need to change this whole process to first page only i need my select box (i.e. Workgroup & Project Type dropdown) should come to first page only where i have my list to select the value and update button on click of that the node values should update and i return back to the same page..

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to understand exactly what you mean but I think an answer I wrote before might help since VBO doesn't really do what you want it to.

[How to bulk delete selected content/nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192969/how-to-bulk-delete-selected-content-nodes-in-drupal-7/193021#193021)

[image]

Follow the link if that "one page" functionality is what you need. It's limited but it works.

Comment: my requirement is is when user will view this page he should be able to get the 2 dropdown with submit button. don't want that next page for selecting the values form dropdown

Comment: That's what this solution provides.

Comment: can u tell the steps how i can achieve this?

Comment: I'm quite busy but I will get round go this hopefully today or tomorrow. Comment again if it looks like I forget.