# How to create a Privatemsg thread with multiple recipients in a Rules component?

Tags: 7, rules, privatemsg, actions

I'd like to send private messages to a selected group of users. For this purpose I use a view with VBO and a Rules component action (utilizing the "Send message" action provided by Privatemsg) - as  described [in this question.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200302/how-to-display-a-form-filled-by-a-vbo-submission)

However, I still have a minor issue with it: Since I send the messages looping through the list of users, privatemsg module sends individual messages and doesn't create a thread with multiple users. Is it possible to use the whole array of users in a single "Send message" action?

Probably one solution might be to use cutoms PHP code in rules component and create thred with [privatemsg_new_thread](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_new_thread/7) function. But it's not a very drupalish way, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a rule component with custom php code. It needs some changes in privatmsg module, see in this discussion: https://www.drupal.org/node/2725325